# FluentValidation - Using a collection of validators validating the same class

Tags: fluentvalidation

Looking at the examples, it seems like the expected pattern for validating an object `Foo` is to set all the validation rules in one `AbstractValidator<Foo>` class.

However, I think it can be good to separate business logic of different validations to separate `AbstractValidator<Foo>` classes, when the validations are more complex, especially when having to call external services for the validations.

I know I can implement different `AbstractValidator<Foo>` and call them from a list/array,
but I am wondering, since this is a repeated pattern for me,
Is there any way to facilitate this?

I am looking for some class that get a list of `AbstractValidator<Foo>` and aggregate the results, optionally also running them in parallel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FluentValidation multiple validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198471/fluentvalidation-multiple-validators)

Comment: @WimOmbelets I saw this post, in my case I am trying to call different validations for `FOO` and not different validations of different properties of `FOO`

Comment: @alex.dev hi there. If you have a non-identical question to this one, please research it - maybe it's been answered here already - and if not then by all means post it. I'm sure there's a good chance you'll get it answered.